# Oracle Entity Framework/Managed Data Access Core and connection pool leak with proxy user

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

We have recently upgraded from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (we are on .net standard 2.0). When we connect to the database we use proxy credentials, with the following connection string:

**User Id=changingUserId;Data Source=dbname;Proxy User Id=proxyUserId;Proxy Password=proxyUserPassword;**

The UserID element changes based on who is connecting.

The problem we have is that the connection pools are no longer working as expected, with many connections being spawning and not closed - we very quickly reach the pool size limit and everything grinds to halt.  Before the upgrade, pools would increase and decrease in size, but they now only grow!

Reading the oracle docs, it appears it requires the connection string to be identical for connection pooling to work correctly, but I don't see how this is possible when we are using proxy users. Has anyone else come across this/got around it or am I missing something?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I would ask here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/odp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a work around, adding the users password into the connection string makes it work as expected - no more filling up the connection pool/connection numbers are again rising and falling.

**User Id=changingUserId;*Password=usersPwd*;Data Source=dbname;Proxy User Id=proxyUserId;Proxy Password=proxyUserPassword;**

This isn't ideal for us - authentication/authorisation is handled elsewhere - but it will do for now. We are raising a call with Oracle as I suspect this is a bug in their library.